# Calibrating one timeseries with another

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, similarity, calibration

I have two timeseries in two different dataframes. What is the best way to find the calibration coefficient between them?

I was thinking to substrack one dataframe from another and divide with datapoints. But I am not sure if this works because these two different dataframes are from different measurement devices, so different time values.

```
df1[] - df2[] / (amount of datapoints)
```

[image]

For example, the bottom graph (black) is concentration and the red graph is intensity. When I would measure only the intensity, using the calibration value or formula, I could derive the concentration values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can store the intensity and concentration measurements in a common dataframe, with one column for the time of the measurements, one column for intensity and one column for concentration, and missing values where appropriate;
- Then fill missing values with `pandas.DataFrame.interpolate`;
- Finally, you can find what you called the "calibration" as a linear regression.

##### Store intensity and concentration in a dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# MAKE MEASUREMENTS  (I'll admit I'm just measuring sinuses)
t0, t1 = 0, 32

n_points_intensity = 50
time_intensity = np.random.uniform(t0, t1, n_points_intensity)
intensity = 10 * np.sin(time_intensity) + np.random.normal(0,0.1,n_points_intensity)

n_points_concentration = 50
time_concentration = np.random.uniform(t0, t1, n_points_concentration)
concentration = np.sin(time_concentration) + np.random.normal(0,0.1,n_points_concentration)

# STORE MEASUREMENTS IN ONE DATAFRAME WITH MISSING VALUES
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': np.concatenate((time_intensity, time_concentration)),
                   'intensity': np.concatenate((intensity, [np.NaN]*n_points_concentration)),
                   'concentration': np.concatenate(([np.NaN]*n_points_intensity, concentration))
}).sort_values(by='time', ignore_index=True)
print(df)

# OUTPUT
         time  intensity  concentration
0    0.337827        NaN       0.309016
1    0.402861   3.920522            NaN
2    0.544032   5.175905            NaN
3    0.615081        NaN       0.542628
4    0.726053   6.639234            NaN
..        ...        ...            ...
95  60.408141  -6.577897            NaN
96  61.571468  -9.522081            NaN
97  61.899227        NaN      -0.729130
98  62.182529  -6.046479            NaN
99  62.857848        NaN       0.093763

[100 rows x 3 columns]
```

##### Fill missing values with `pandas.DataFrame.interpolate`:

```py
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)
df.interpolate(method='index', inplace=True)
df.dropna(inplace=True)  # this should only drop the first row
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(df)

# OUTPUT
time       intensity  concentration                               
0.402861    3.920522       0.363813
0.544032    5.175905       0.482763
0.615081    5.747088       0.542628
0.726053    6.639234       0.577253
...              ...            ...
60.408141  -6.577897      -0.601758
61.571468  -9.522081      -0.701132
61.899227  -7.657847      -0.729130
62.182529  -6.046479      -0.485939
62.857848  -6.046479       0.093763

[99 rows x 3 columns]
```

##### Perform linear regression to get relationship between intensity and concentration

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

reg = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False).fit(
    np.array(df['intensity']).reshape(-1,1),
    df['concentration']
)
a, b = reg.coef_[0], reg.intercept_
# concentration = a * intensity + b
```

Comment: Thank you for the example script. Unfortunately I have problem installing the sklearn module. In Spyder console it says the module is installed (using !pip list), but when I run your example script, I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

Comment: @fred Instead of using `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression`, you can use [`numpy.linalg.lstsq`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html). If you know that `b=0`, then you can get `a` as `from np.linalg import lstsq; X = np.array(df['intensity']).reshape(-1, 1); y = df['concentration']; a = lstsq(X, y, rcond=None)[0].item()`

Comment: And if `b` is not supposed to be 0 then same thing but change `X = np.vstack([df['intensity'], np.ones(len(df.index))]).T` and then `a, b = lstsq(X, y, rcond=None)[0]`

Comment: Thank you for your help! Just in case I tested in Excel with generated values and the script gives the same a, b values (slope, intercept).